# highchart json ajax issue

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Im pretty new to web development, i usually work on things on the server side.  I'm working on a little hobby electronic project where i have a netduino server json requests on my lan.  The netduino returns json in this format:

```
[ { "sensor" : "bk", "temp" : "68.9000015", "time" : "01/01/2009 01:04:46"},{ "sensor" : "mt", "temp" : "69.0124969", "time" : "01/01/2009 01:04:46"},{ "sensor" : "hlt", "temp" : "68.9000015", "time" : "01/01/2009 01:04:46"} ]
```

I would like to have the sensors be my seriess {bk,mt,hlt} (there are two more series not in this return)

My ajax request does not seem to be sending gets to my netduino, im monitoring requests in httpfox and dont see anything to 192.168.0.11...

Here is the js:

```
    //data arrays for holding the points
    var HLT=[],
        MT =[],
        BK =[],
        PC =[],
        CL =[];
    var chart;

    //after DOM is loaded setup timeout to call the ajax method
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(reqData, 5000);

        options.series[0].data = HLT;
        options.series[1].data = MT;
        options.series[2].data = BK;
        options.series[3].data = PC;
        options.series[4].data = CL;

        //call function to render the chart and setup the options
        renderChart();

    });

    //this function requests the data
    function reqData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.0.11/"+Math.random(),//using math.random to avoid browser caching
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",             
        success: mergeData(data)
    });
    }

    //this function merges the data and refreshes the table
    function mergeData(data){
    //$(this).addClass("done");
    }

    function renderChart(){
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }
```

the chart renders when the page loads but i don't see reqData being invoked.  Please help.  Also what is a good way to update the series data ?  Im not good with javascript would a foreach matching on series name work?  I want to chart the temp(y axis) and datetime(x axis) of the temps.

Thanks!

---edit 1/23/2012---

I wasnt very clear on what the issue is sorry, in this function:

```
    //after DOM is loaded setup timeout to call the ajax method
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(reqData, 5000);

        options.series[0].data = HLT;
        options.series[1].data = MT;
        options.series[2].data = BK;
        options.series[3].data = PC;
        options.series[4].data = CL;

        //call function to render the chart and setup the options
        renderChart();

    });
```

The reqData() function is not getting fired (verified through not seeing get requests to 192.168.0.11 in httpfox), however renderChart() is getting invoked...  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I saw you posted data to an IP. Is this in same domain as where you host this page? If not, you are trying to make a request to a different domain. In that case, you would have to use JSONP to make this work. See JSONP at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Thay ip is a NAT'd ip on my lan.  This page is going to be local to my lan both the webserver hosting the page, and my service returning the json are local.  Im mot really doing a post either, at,least im not intending to, justa get.

Comment: If your page and the running service are on the same host, I would recommend using explicit path for the Ajax URL - `/path/to/the/page`. Are you sure the url for your AJAX request is `"http://192.168.0.11/"+Math.random()`? Also, for JSONP, it only works for GET if I remember correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  The ajax client and server are not on the same host.  Client .0.104 and server is 0.11.  Im sure about the url.  that is where I got the example data from.

Comment: So that means you have to use JSONP to implement this.

Comment: im a little confused as to what JSONP is... Do I need to change my service to return ContentType:"application/JSONP"?  I looked on the jquery site but it doesn't provide much info on JSOP.  If my return header looks like this will it work?

(Status-Line) HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length 375
Connection close

Comment: Two important things with JSONP: 1) when you make quest, make sure the URL ends with a string and "=", for example, `?jsoncallback=?`; 2) in your service, make sure the response begins with a "padding", for example, "jQuery1710013680923962965608_1327379974217" - a string plus some random number. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP about how JSONP works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is not another issue that might be getting "in the way"?  The call to request the data looks correct; I put it in the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/malonso/cJ3TJ/3/

Do you see any javascript errors when you go to your page?